# Vue router scrollBehavior returns same path for both to and from

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to check the `to` and `from` of the route path with `scrollBehavior` to manage the scroll behaviour.

```
global.router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        console.log('>>> to', to);
        console.log('>>> from', from);
        switch (to.path) {
            case '/in-list':
                break;
            case '/your-list':
                break;
            default:
                return {x: 0, y: 0}
        }
    },
    mode: 'history',
});
```

Suppose, I navigate from **About** page to the **In-List** or **Your-list** page, I would like to `return {x: 0, y: 0}`. However, when navigating between **In-list** or **Your-list** I would like no such behaviour.

However, both `to` and `from` return the same path. They both return the `to.path` so I cannot check where it was navigated `from`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was with my version. I was using `^2.2.1` and upgraded to the latest version `2.7.0`. However, this issue was fixed in version `2.3.1`.

I saw the issue in the [closed issues of Vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1207). Hope this will help some one.